# Migrating Accounts

Tags: feature-request, openid, login

I started with a gmail login, which I associated with a bunch of stackoverflow and stackexchange sites. Then I wanted to get into DNS, so I got myself a new domain and a google sites account.

The short story is I just changed OpenIDs, and I want to change them everywhere.

So for some respective stack-* sites, I've

- added a second openid to the list (non gmail)
- logged in via this address, associated my new account (google sites' mail)
- logged back in with the openid I intend to identify myself with

I haven't found a way to move house with Carriers yet though.

It would be really cool if there was a way to propagate this through all my accounts.

There's already a way to associate account personal details, would it be possible to have something similar for login credentials?